# Determining all the elements of S4?

Tags: group-theory

What is an easy way to determine the elements of $S_{4}$?

While going through my revision process in an attempt to stem out the nitty gritty areas that I am unsure of, I chanced upon this.
I tried to search for an answer via Google but there are no satisfying responses.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just consider all the permutation over 4 elements.

Comment: I am unable to start. I know the order of S4 is 24. So I expect 24 permutation elements i S4.

Comment: $S_4=\{(1)(2)(3)(4),
 (1,3)(2,4),
 (1,4)(2,3),
 (1,2)(3,4),
 (2,3,4),
 (1,3,2),
 (1,4,3),
 (1,2,4),
 (2,4,3),
 (1,3,4),
 (1,4,2),
 (1,2,3),
 (3,4),
 (1,3,2,4),
 (1,4,2,3),
 (1,2),
 (2,3),
 (1,3,4,2),
 (1,4),
 (1,2,4,3),
 (2,4),
 (1,3),
 (1,4,3,2),
 (1,2,3,4)\}$

Answer (score 5):

List all possible 4-letter words in the letters $1,2,3,4$ without repetition.

A systematic way is to list them in lexicographical order:

```
1234
1243
1324
1342
...
4321
```

A word $a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4$ corresponds to the permutation $i \mapsto a_i$ in $S_4$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations.

Answer (score -1):

Start with the identity (1)(2)(3)(4).

Now start by introducing some transpositions:

(1, 2)(3)(4),
(1,2)(3,4),
(1)(2,3)(4),
(1,4)(2,3),

...

Then you do triples

(1,2,3)(4),
(1)(2,3,4),

...

Finally (1,2,3,4)

If you think of the parenthesis as spacers and open a probability coursebook, there are some efficient ways to go about getting all 24

Answer (score -2):

We know that every element of $S_4$ is an automorphism over ${1,2,3,4}$.
We want to count the number of elements in $S_4$ then lets start with $1$, it must be mapped to an element in ${1,2,3,4}$ - so it has 4 options, now for 2 - he has only 3 options for mapping (since $1$ already occupied an element in ${1,2,3,4}$), in the same way $3$ has $2$ options, and the mapping of $4$ is determined uniquely after determining all the other mappings.

Therefore, we finally get $4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 4! = 24$ such elements.

Comment: This gives the number of elements, but not the elements themselves.

Comment: You right, but using this process it's easy to determine the elements.